# React Redux Starter Kit with hot reloading and backend server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-hot-loader

I am starting to learn react with redux and I would really like to use this https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit starter project for my journey.

Its clean, simple and I would like to build something little bigger with it than what I do now. For that I need backend server. I already have one written in express and I been using it with my angular app. But I simply cannot wrap my head around how I should make it work with this starter kit. Its using koa running on port 3000 for hot-reloading functionality and I cant make this two (hot-reloading/api) work at the same time. For someone experienced it should be really easy to plug into all of this simple express server with one route also running on port 3000 from that I should be able to figure out the rest.

I would share my code with you but I have none because I dont even know where to start. There are so many plugins/moving parts which you need to understand that it makes my head spin:) so my plan is to start working on some project using all of this and learn everything along the way.

Answer (score 0):

There are some starter kits [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/master/docs#starter-kits), including few with backend part implemented. I would suggest to take different and try them out. IMHO, the best way to lear it is to take the simplest boilerplate and to expand step-by-step by yourself ))